# VSCode Pylance false-positive (?) reaction on ImportError

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, suppress-warnings, pylance

I am trying to write cross-platform app in python. I want to use uvloop (only if possible), using this code:

```py
import asyncio

try:
    import uvloop
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(uvloop.EventLoopPolicy())
except ImportError:
    pass
```

However, pylance shows message that "Import "uvloop" could not be resolved" in Windows (because uvloop is not available for this OS, so that's okay). It's not a big deal, everything works, but this message is annoying. I can set ignore rule, but I want to keep other unresolved import warnings, because in other cases they are pretty useful. How can I tell Pylance, that in this specific case I'm okay with it?

Comment: Thanks to S.B, solved with `# pyright: ignore[reportMissingImports]` next to the `import uvloop` line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set an inline ignore statement:

```py
import asyncio


try:
    import uvloop # type: ignore
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(uvloop.EventLoopPolicy())
except ImportError:
    pass
```

It'd be better to be more specific with the rule you want to ignore. The above will ignore all type checking errors.

https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/196#issuecomment-668099106